# UglifyJS throws error Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

I currently have this

```
ready : function(){
    bus.$on('a-data', (param) => {
        this.name = param.name;
        this.age = param.age;
    })
},
```

While this particular code run when `uglifyjs` is disabled, when enabled it throws the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)
```

Here's my uglify config

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    minimize: true,
    sourceMap: false,
    compress: {
        warnings: false,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        conditionals: true,
        booleans: true,
        unused: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
        drop_console: true
    }
}))
```

I can't seem to understand why it's not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-electron/issues/41

Comment: Single argument arrow functions don't require parenthesis, `bus.$on('a-data', (param) => {` should be `bus.$on('a-data', param => {`

Comment: @Roberrrt this doesn't work!

Comment: I was under the impression UglifyJS supported ES6, but that isn't the case I suppose. Check @CodingWithSpike's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UglifyJS does not have ES6/Harmony support built in yet.

They have an [open GitHub issue for tracking the status of that feature](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448).

---

This is usually not an issue because most people tend to run their ES6 code through Babel first for back compatibility with old browsers, and the result of that would pass through Uglify.

Comment: though i ran all my codes through Babel. Then, I am using uglify :/

Comment: What babel presets are you using? If you use the es2015 presets, babel will replace the arrow function with a standard function. Another anternative might be to try Babili instead of Uglify: https://github.com/babel/babili